# INDEX MATCH with different sizes of arrays

Tags: excel

I am trying to link dividends of several stocks to a range of dates. The dividends are several months apart, where column A is the date and column B is the amount of the dividend. Each stock has about 10-20 dividend payments in the last 5 years. I am now trying to distribute these dividend payouts across a daily timeline, where column A shows daily dates from today until 2005 (3818 rows).

I tried to do this with INDEX/MATCH with the following formula:

```
=INDEX([A68U.SI.csv]A68U.SI!$B$2:$B$13,MATCH([A68U.SI.csv]A68U.SI!$A2,$A2:$A3818))
```

However, I get a #REF error. This seems to be the wrong approach. Does anyone have an idea? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,[A68U.SI.csv]A68U.SI!$A$2:$B$13,2,FALSE)
```

To remove errors for dates when there are no paid dividends:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,[A68U.SI.csv]A68U.SI!$A$2:$B$13,2,FALSE),"")
```

If you have more than one paid dividend on the same date, you will have to use something different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to switch that around, e.g. in `B2` copied down

`=LOOKUP(A2,[A68U.SI.csv]A68U.SI!$A$2:$B$13)`

That will lookup the `A2` date in Your payment table and find the relevant dividend for that date.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I get the same value for all dates to a certain point, and then get #N/A.

Comment: OK, I may have misinterpreted your requirement - you said you want to distribute the payments, I interpreted that as finding what the dividend was for a specific date - is that not the case? Perhaps you can edit your question to show some sample data and required output

Comment: Just found the answer. I need to invert the INDEX MATCH and then it works. Thanks!

Comment: So what formula did you use? - LOOKUP can achieve the same as INDEX/MATCH assuming you are using MATCH with no 3rd argument as per the formula in your question (so it defaults to 1 or TRUE)

Comment: I used the following formula:

=INDEX([A68U.SI.csv]A68U.SI!$B$2:$B$13,MATCH($A2,[A68U.SI.csv]A68U.SI!$A2:$A3818))